# Drawing a Shape Using a Button (Python Tkinter)

Tags: python, button, canvas, tkinter

Is it possible to bind a button to a function that draws a shape on the canvas?

I have this section of code:

```
def option(*args):
global missguess
missguess=missguess+1
if missguess==1:
    w.create_oval(210,100,295,175,width=3)
if missguess==2:
    w.create_line(249,175,249,285,width=3)
if missguess==3:
    w.create_line(249,200,270,250,width=3)
if missguess==4:
    w.create_line(249,200,228,250,width=3)
if missguess==5:
    w.create_line(249,285,228,350,width=3)
if missguess==6:
    w.create_line(249,285,270,350,width=3)
    print("You Lose!")
```

And this option function is bound to a number of buttons. I keep getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'create_oval'
```

I have tried to make functions inside the option function that draws the shapes like this:

```
def option(*args):
global missguess
missguess=missguess+1
if missguess==1:
   def oval():
      w.create_oval(210,100,295,175,width=3)
```

but then nothing shows up on the canvas. I'm not sure if there is even a way to do this.

Comment: Does your button object have a `create_oval` method? Buttons by default don't have such a method.

Comment: error means that `w` is Button, not Canvas and you try to do `Button.create_oval`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible, you define the function and then place it's name within the 'command' parameter of the button.
This code is just a general example of how it works, hope this helps

```
import Tkinter

window = Tkinter.Tk()

canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(window, width=640, height=480)
canvas.pack()

def draw_circle():
    canvas.create_oval(25,25,70,70)

button = Tkinter.Button(window, text="draw circle", command=draw_circle)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```